# GitActions : How do you invoke an older version of a Workflow

Tags: github-actions

In Github actions how is it possible to run a Workflow from a different branch other than master
or how is it possible to run an older version of a workflow based on a commit tag value ?

Can we get it embedded in the url , something like this ?
`https://github.com/<repo>/<org>/actions/workflows/exec_proc.yml?commit=2abe4b8`

Comment: You can use `workflow_call` with a reference to the workflow's tag or branch name

Comment: What triggers does the workflow have?